# Fastest way to do MySQL query select with WHERE clauses on an unindexed table

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a very big unindexed table called table with rows like this:

```
IP              entrypoint              timestamp
171.128.123.179 /page-title/?kw=abc     2016-04-14 11:59:52
170.45.121.111  /another-page/?kw=123   2016-04-12 04:13:20
169.70.121.101  /a-third-page/          2016-05-12 09:43:30
```

I want to make the fastest query that, given 30 IPs and one date, will search rows as far back a week before that date and return the most recent row that contains "?kw=" for each IP. So I want DISTINCT entrypoints but only the most recent one.

I'm stuck by this I know it's a relatively simple INNER JOIN but I don't know the fastest way to do it.

By the way: I can't add the index right now because it's very big and on a db that serves a website. I'm going to replace it with an indexed table don't worry.

Comment: Without indexes, whatever is your query, it will be slow and the speed differences will be minimal. Mysql is all about indexes.

Comment: Without an index, the engine will have to do a full table scan.  If you have a limit clause it may stop early, but there are no shortcuts it can take.  (If you're unsure, do an EXPLAIN on the query.)

Comment: how big is "very big"?

Comment: You could recreate the table as a memory table and see if that helps: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: As others said, without an index you'll have a full table scan and improvement from optimization will be minimal. On MySQL 5.6+ you can create some indexes without a table copy. If you're running an older version you can create a copy of the table with the indexes you need, populate and rename it. Having a timestamp makes it even easier. You won't have any downtime on your website if you do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows from the table

```
SELECT ...
  FROM very_big_unindexed_table t
```

only within the past week...

```
 WHERE t.timestamp >= NOW() + INTERVAL - 1 WEEK
```

that contains '?kw=' in the entry point

```
   AND t.entrypoint LIKE '%?kw=%'
```

only the latest row for each IP.  There's a couple of approaches to that. A correlated subquery on a very big unindexed table is going to eat your lunch and your lunch box. And without an index, there's no getting around a full scan of the table and a "Using filesort" operation.

Given the unfortunate circumstances, our best bet for performance is likely going to be getting the set whittled down as small as we can, and then perform the sort, and avoid any join operations (back to that table) and avoid correlated subqueries.

So, let's start with something like this, to return *all* of the rows from the past week with '?kw=' in entry point. This is going to be full scan of the table, and a sort operation...

```
         SELECT t.ip
              , t.timestamp
              , t.entry_point
           FROM very_big_unindexed_table t
          WHERE t.timestamp >= NOW() + INTERVAL -1 WEEK
            AND t.entrypoint LIKE '%?kw=%'
          ORDER BY t.ip DESC, t.timestamp DESC
```

We can use an unsupported trick with user-defined variables. (The MySQL Reference Manual specifically warns against using a pattern like this, because the behavior is (officially) *undefined*. Unofficially, the optimizer in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5 (at least) is very predictable.

I think this is going to be about as good as you are going to get, if the number of rows from the past week are significant subset of the entire table. This is going to create a sizable intermediate resultset (derived table), if there are lot of rows that satisfy the predicates.

```
SELECT q.ip
     , q.entrypoint
     , q.timestamp
  FROM (
         SELECT IF(t.ip = @prev_ip, 0, 1) AS new_ip
              , @prev_ip  := t.ip         AS ip
              , t.timestamp               AS timestamp
              , t.entrypoint              AS entrypoint
           FROM (SELECT @prev_ip := NULL) i
          CROSS
           JOIN very_big_unindexed_table t
          WHERE t.timestamp >= NOW() + INTERVAL -1 WEEK
            AND t.entrypoint LIKE '%?kw=%'
          ORDER BY t.ip DESC, t.timestamp DESC
       ) q
 WHERE q.new_ip
```

Execution of that query will require (in terms of what's going to take the time)

- a full scan of the table (there's no way to get around that)
- a sort operation (again, there's no way around that)
- materializing a derived table containing all of the rows that satisfy the predicates
- a pass through the derived table to pull out the "latest" row for each IP

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it makes a lot more sense to me now.